# Retaining nuisence columns in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas

I have a moderate sized data set I am processing with pandas. It has around 600,000 rows.

It has three "id" variables: "gene_id", "gene_name" and "transcript_id", and then a number of numerical columns which are determined at run-time.

```
In [129]: df.head().todict()
{u'utr3_count': {8: 2.0, 30: 1.0, 29: 2.0, 6: 2.0, 7: 2.0}, 
 u'gene_id': {8: u'ENSG00000188157', 30: u'ENSG00000160087', 29: u'ENSG00000176022', 6: u'ENSG00000188157', 7: u'ENSG00000188157'}, 
 u'utr3_enrichment': {8: 2.1449912126499999, 30: 1.14988290398, 29: 1.0484234234200001, 6: 2.1449912126499999, 7: 2.1449912126499999},
 u'transcript_id': {8: u'ENST00000379370', 30: u'ENST00000450390', 29: u'ENST00000379198', 6: u'ENST00000379370', 7: u'ENST00000379370'},
 u'expression': {8: 0.13387876534027521, 30: 0.514855687606112, 29: 0.79126387397064091, 6: 0.13387876534027521, 7: 0.13387876534027521}, 
 u'gene_name': {8: u'AGRN', 30: u'UBE2J2', 29: u'B3GALT6', 6: u'AGRN', 7: u'AGRN'}}
```

I want to get the mean of the replicates for each "transcript_id". But doing so by grouping on "transcript_id" means that I lose the information on "gene_id" and "gene_name" as they are classed as nuisance columns.

If I group on all three columns, I immediately get MemoryError, even on a big box (128GB), as pandas tries to do the calculation for every combination of the values in the three columns, even though this is definitely not necessary: each "transcript_id" maps to a single "gene_id" and a single "gene_name".

Is there a way to do the groupby just on transcript_id without losing the information in the other columns?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Simple Solution:**

Store `transcript_id`, `gene_id` and `gene_name` in a separate DataFrame (say `metadata`):

```
metadata = df[['transcript_id', 'gene_id', 'gene_name']].copy()
# .copy() is important!
```

`groupby` on `transcript_id` as you do now, and perform your calculations (say `agg_df`). After they are done, merge the two frames together:

```
pd.merge(agg_df, metadata, how='left', on='transcript_id)
```

This works because

> ... each "transcript_id" maps to a single "gene_id" and a single
>   "gene_name"

---

**Alternate Solution:**

Read the file (assuming you are reading from csv) in chunks using `pd.read_csv(file_path, chunksize = <some integer, say 5e4>)`. `groupby` on all three columns, (you won't run into `MemoryError` now because you are only reading part of the data) and keep running totals and running counts. Divide the totals by the counts at the end. Pseudo code:

```
totals = pd.DataFrame()
counts = pd.DataFrame()
df = pd.read_csv(file_path, chunksize=5e4)
for chunk in df:
    grouped = chunk.groupby(['transcript_id', 'gene_id', 'gene_name'])
    totals = totals.add(grouped.sum())
    counts = counts.add(grouped.count())
means = totals/counts
```

This will work as long as you need some measure that can be computed in bits and pieces, like sums, counts, products, cumulative sums and products. But anything like percentiles or

---

*Another solution (slightly harder):* Merge the columns `transcript_id`, `gene_id` and `gene_name` in another column, say `merged_id` and `groupby` on `merged_id`. Split the column up into the components at the end of your calculations.

---

Ps. I recommend using the Simple Solution.

Comment: Thanks. I went with the simple solution (at least in part because I don't get the data from a csv, but from a module I don't have control over). Feels a little clunky especially as its something I have to do all the time. I'm going to wait to see if anything else comes along. Will marks as answer if not.